# How to make a vector perpendicular to a plane in a plot?

Tags: python, animation, math, vector, 3d

I have made a plot based on three equations and a circle on the same plot. Any ideas how I can make it constantly perpendicular to the blue(magenta) vector as it goes through all iterations? Yes, I have posted simmilar questions before, I am a student clawing his way through one of the final works of the degree and I appreciate any kind of help. Here's the core part of the code:

```
for t in range(len(theta)):
    fig = plt.figure('Parametrinai blynai')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(x[1:t], y[1:t], z[1:t], '-r', linewidth=3)
    ax.azim = 0
    ax.dist = 10
    ax.elev = 25

    ax.set_xlabel('X', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
    ax.set_xlim([-20, 20])
    ax.set_ylim([-20, 20])
    ax.set_zlim([-10, 10])
    plt.title('Parametrinis blynas', fontweight='bold', fontsize=16)

    #plotting the three vectors following the point

    ax.quiver(x[t - 1], y[t - 1], z[t - 1], emp * T[t, 0], emp * T[t, 1], emp * T[t, 2], color='r')#raudona
    ax.quiver(x[t - 1], y[t - 1], z[t - 1], emp * B[t, 0], emp * B[t, 1], emp * B[t, 2], color='b')#melyna
    ax.quiver(x[t - 1], y[t - 1], z[t - 1], emp * N[t, 0], emp * N[t, 1], emp * N[t, 2], color='g')#zalia

    ax.quiver(0, 0, z[t-1],emp * B[t, 0], emp * B[t, 1], emp * B[t, 2], color='m')#magenta

    # circle
    cx=[]
    cy=[]
    cz=[]
    cp=360
    for p in range(cp):
        cx.append(r * np.cos(np.pi*2.*p/(cp-1)))
        cy.append(r * np.sin(np.pi*2.*p/(cp-1)) * np.cos(theta[t])- h * np.sin(theta[t]))
        cz.append(r * np.sin(np.pi*2.*p/(cp-1)) * np.sin(theta[t]) + h * np.cos(theta[t]))
        #x = r * np.cos(phi)
        #y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta) - h * np.sin(theta)
        #z = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta) + h * np.cos(theta)
        #phi and theta are lists of angles, generated by specific equations


    ax.plot(cx, cy, cz, color='m')
```

Also, I'm adding the second and fourth iterations to illustrate what I'm talking about
[image]
[image]

Comment: If `a` and `b` are two noncolinear vectors in a plane, then the cross-product `c = a × b` is a vector orthogonal to that plane. If you're using numpy, there is [numpy.cross](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html).

Comment: So I should define two noncolinear vectors in the circle's plane and make the cross product equal to the blue/magenta vector?

Comment: @Stef     I've tried to come up with something using your comment, but did not get anywhere. I've managed to make the magenta vector parallel to the blue vector, but the I've failed to make the circle perpendicular. I've got an idea that the problem might be the equations of the circle (cx, cy, cz). Maybe you could further help me with this?